# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Well, Mathematica's very first [moderator election](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to an end. Our winners are:

[image: RM] [image: J. M.] [image: Mr. Wizard] [image: Verbeia]

Please give them a warm welcome, and hearty thanks and congratulations for volunteering!

Also, a sincere thank you our other [Moderator Pro Tempore](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), [Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/), who (along with J. M. and Mr.Wizard) helped shepherd the site through its beta.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/1).

Finally, I need to apologize to Verbeia - I rushed through running the votes the first time around, and incorrectly identified her as the third-place winner instead of J.M. To be fair, it was neck and neck - obviously both of you were very popular candidates. To make this up, we've decided to appoint *four* winners for this election - it was my mistake, not hers, and given how successful this site has been so far it certainly can't hurt to have another hand on deck.

Comment: No worries. By the way, I am a girl :)

Comment: Ouch. Another mistake for me! ;-)

Comment: Actually I am a Celtic goddess

Comment: Oh, good - less than an hour as a mod, and you've already got the god complex down!

Comment: Congrats folks! Any clue about when the new crew will be starting?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries We already have our diamonds... strange seeing you without one.

Comment: @r.M. I hadn't noticed. I hope this 4 mod crew situation will be continued after your term. It will make the decision for me to run a lot easier.

Comment: All hail the Hypnotoad! And his toadies! (For those who don't know me, no I couldn't resist, nor did I want to!)

Comment: @r.m. With J.M. and mr.wiz having decided to go on there will probably no need for me to hand over spicy details; or, perhaps, we can have a last (for me) meeting in the mod room.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries This is technically for life... unless someone decides to drop out or something goes horribly wrong. Come next election, you should run. The break now would probably do you good (and you can earn a Marshall badge which the rest of us can't). Btw, I'm in the mod room now (your access hasn't been removed yet)

Comment: Congratulations for all the new and retired moderators and thanks for the hard work. Is there any way to see for whom I have cast my votes? There are holes (exclusions?) in my memory.

Comment: Congratulation to the moderators. Well and truly deserved. Nice call to have 4 moderators instead of 3. Special thanks to the retiring moderators who have managed to get us smoothly through the beta.

Comment: Congrats, as Matariki already said: well and truly deserved!

Comment: @István, you should be able to still see your original picks on [this page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election).